# Is this open/close JDBC connection code ok?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I'm not sure if this code is correct. I get it from an example of my Java course but I see that in fact it never closes the connection and the exceptions doesn't look to be catched correctly. (I call the query methods from my business tier).

```
public class Persistence {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB";
    static final String USER = "user";
    static final String PASS = "pass";
    private static Connection con;

    static {
        openConnection();
    }

    private static boolean openConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            return true;
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("SQL problem: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    //----------EXAMPLE QUERY-----------
    public static String someQuery() throws SQLException {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT column FROM myDB");
        String data;
        while (rs.next()) {
            data = rs.getString("column");
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Should I open and close the connection inside every query method and delete the "static{}" expression?
Like this? (still not sure about the exceptions):

```
public static String someQuery() throws SQLException {
    openConnection();
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT column FROM myDB");
    String data;
    while (rs.next()) {
        data = rs.getString("column");
    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();
    return data;
    }
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why is everything static?  There's a syntax error - where you write `String data =;`.  There are other problems where you call `close()` on variables that might be null.

Comment: I guess this is all simplyfied for the sake of readability. It is a course, after all. Most people would go for some kind of connection pooling.

Comment: @DavidWallace, I missed the String thing (edited). About the     close()  should I code something like:
    `if(con != null){con.close()}`

Comment: There are plenty of examples online about how to use the various `close()` methods properly (with null checks and finally blocks).  Do worry about the static nature of everything though - this kind of class is a nightmare for testability.  It's worth going to a good deal of trouble to avoid the use of static methods.

Comment: @Fildor, I simplyfied myself to post it. I used this code in my application and it works... the thing is that I'm not sure this is a good practice refered to connections. I read about connection pooling but it seems quite complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `static` block is only executed once, so you open a single connection and then keep it open for the duration of the program.

That does work but is flawed for a number of reasons. For example as soon as you start multi-threading it is completely useless.

Your second example is better but still flawed, the best approach would be:

1. Use a connection pool to keep the connections open, request one from the pool when you need it.
2. Use a try-finally block to ensure you always close the connection and/or return it to the pool when done.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I'll go for the second example with your second tip. Then I'll put my hands at some connection pool study D:

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a new instance of JDBC Driver class

1)    Change this to Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance() to Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER)

You just need to register the class with the JVM(which involves intialization of static variables and blocks)

2)Try creating connection thread pool as suggested above

3)Use a `try with resources` block for Connection,Statement and ResultSet as all the three interfaces extend `java.lang.AutoCloseable`.As such,your resources are always closed without you having to write boiler plate code.Also,the exception in your business logic does not get masked by any exception occuring while closing a resource in finally block.

But of course you know JDK7 for that.These were implemnted as part of Project Coin.Just google it and you will get more information

Comment: Not creating a new instance of JDBC driver class will help you do away with InstantiationException and IllegalAccessException